# Singleton issue

Tags: unity, c#, design-patterns

I have two scenes, The first one called "Boot" contains and ObjectPoller class that instantiates all GameObject in the game and disable them. I made it a singleton with "don't destroyOnLoad" attribute. In the the second scene called GamePlay, There is a LevelManager that get acces to the ObjectPooler of the first scene by a function called GetPooledObject. When I boot the game by the first scene (Boot) in the Unity editor, everything works fine. But when I boot the game by the second scene, Unity editor freezes completely. I can't even shut it down. I'm  do ctrl + Alt+delete to stop Unity. Is there any logic to prevent this behaviour?

```
 // in the ObjectPooler file

private PoolInfo GetPoolByType(PoolObjectType type)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allPoolObjectList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (type == allPoolObjectList[i].type)
            return allPoolObjectList[i];
    }
    return null;
}

// In the LevelManager 
private void Spawn(BlocType _type)
{
    if (ObjectPooler.Instance != null)
    {
        Bloc b = ObjectPooler.Instance.GetPooledBloc(_type);
        if (b)
        {
            // logic
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your object pooler script and how you try to access it, we can't help you. Freezing of unity can have a lot of reasons, one could be an infinite loop. If you make a dedicated boot scene, how do you expect your game to behave when skipping it?

Comment: Excuse me, I will add the script

Answer (score 3):

While I can't be certain, you have most likely a loop error in your `//logic` bloc. But why does it work when you load the `boot` scene first? You have a second mistake. `if (b)` is always true as long as `b` is extended from `MonoBehaviour`.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    private class NullTestClass : MonoBehaviour {
        
    }

    private NullTestClass demo = null;
    
    void Start()
    {
        if (demo)
            Debug.Log("It is null");
        else
            Debug.Log("This gets printed");
    }
}
```

This piece of code prints `This gets printed` even though demo has no value. [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) has the line `This class doesn't support the null-conditional operator (?.) and the null-coalescing operator (??).`

Use the longer null comparison instead.

```
if (demo == null)
   Debug.Log("This gets printed now");
```